# Linux+Windows environement when running Windows application (WSL2)

Tags: python, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm looking for a way to run python package from Windows even though this package requires `gcc` compiler.

I know that from WSL2 Linux I can run Windows application as well and the environment variables are combined (Linux+Windows they are together).

The idea was to install `WSL2` and from Linux run `python.exe` **that is installed on Windows**. I was hoping that python would see both Linux and Windows environment but it seems I was wrong...

When I run:

```py
import os
print(os.environ["PATH"])
```

I can only see Windows path.

Then I tried to manually call `gcc` with full path given to it:

```py
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_call(["//wsl.localhost//Ubuntu//usr//bin//gcc", "--version"]))
```

but I get the error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified`

Moreover it seems python can't find the directory `\\wsl.localhost` as the switching dir command produces error:

```py
os.chdir("\\wsl.localhost")
```

So what I may try to solve my issue? i.e. run python package from Windows even though its dedicated platform is Linux.

Comment: Why is your `gcc` even under wls2 not `"/usr/bin/gcc"`? Are you running python at the cmd or powershell prompt or via a wsl2 bash prompt?

Comment: I run `python.exe` from wsl2 bash (from Ubuntu). If I type `which gcc` from wsl2 (Ubuntu) I get: `/usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: I understood your question and edited the description. I run `python.exe` from Linux WSL2 (i.e. python is installed on Windows).

Comment: No, I want to run Windows python and run wsl/Linux `gcc` (or other Linux executable) from that python

Comment: from windows can you do `wsl gcc` by any chance? perhaps that would be a path forward for subprocess/popen

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'm reading it. The reason why don't want to use Linux pathon is that I want distribute some Windows application which could run these python module if WSL2 is installed. But the application should be installed on Windows

Comment: Yes `wsl gcc --version` works but this is not a good solution as the python package uses `run([gcc, "--version"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL)`. Thus it believes that `gcc` is in `PATH` env variable.